# Is there a way to tell babel to not compile the import and export statements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I'm trying to use babel to compile JSX to js but I don't want to use commonjs. I want to keep the es6 modules import and export. how do I tell babel to ignore them? I'm not using a loader (webpack) yet.

Comment: So how do want to use it? CLI?

Comment: yes I want to use it in CLI